# $_SESSION vs Database vs File

Tags: php, database, performance, session, curl

My problem is: I have a fairly large script that is used to scrape a HTML page (for SEO purposes, nothing dodgy).
Currently I have around 6 or so different functions that are calling the HTML page via cURL, which is obviously not right.

So i need to just fetch the page once via cURL and then store the HTML of that page somewhere temporarily. Considering that the HTML could be anywhere between 10KB to possibly several MB, what would be the best option performance wise?

I'm thinking it would be saving as a temp file and then deleting the file once the script has run. Any guidance or a solution to this problem is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need this file for one php script execution? If it can be seeral MB, save as temporary file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get you right, you use a CLI PHP script to perform these, so the $_SESSION is not relevant here (since you're a client, not a process in a running web server).

Databases are handy to save meaningful data with relations; if you plan on searching (full-text search for example) things in the HTML body, you could do that but I am not sure that you would benefit from the whole database environment. Seems to me that using this would be the same as using a nuke to kill a mosquito.

If you want to save these data for later and process them only one time, or if the files are entirely processed at each iteration, a plain old file is more than enough IMHO (plus you get to use a lot of handy CLI tools like grep, sed, awk if you need to).
Additional bonuses include but are not limited to SVN, Git, full CLI access, API access for locally stored files using whatever scripting / programming language you want, ...

Answer (score 0):

**Session:**

Don't use this superglobal unless you actually have a session.
It seems to me your script runs as a cron-job or something like that, so you don't have a session.

**File:** or **database**

Both are fine choices. In both cases make sure you use the right encoding (don't try to store UTF8 in a latin-9 encoded database, without converting).